# Android: how can I ignore scrolling changes if not done by a specific ScrollView?

Tags: android, scrollview

In my app, I have a ScrollView that listens to Scroll Changes, thanks to the ViewTreeObserver class.

```
scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {
                // I want to directly target this scrollview changes 
                // if specific scrollview { do calculations }
            }
        });
```

However, that class listens to global scroll changes, and I have 3 ScrollViews. So, the main ScrollView is activated and performs the calculations and causes everything to go awry.

Is there a way to ignore other ScrollViews and only target the main one?

Comment: isn't there a .canScroll(true/false) method available where you can "lock" certain things from scrolling... not sure about that, have no studio at hand.
scrollView.setCanScroll(false) or something similar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do to overcome it is store the getScrollX() values (if horizontal scrollview) or the getScrollY() values (if vertical scrollview) in some int and every time an onScrollChanged() is fired, just check if the new scroll Values are different from the ones previously stored.

If they're different, the correct scrollview is being called. If they are the same, the wrong scrollview is being called and therefore ignore it.

```
int prevScrollX_for1 = -1;
int prevScrollX_for2 = -1;

scrollView1.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {
                // Assuming horizontal scrollview

                if(scrollView1.getScrollX() != prevScrollX_for1)
                {
                    // Do something
                }
                prevScrollX_for1 = getScrollX();
            }
        });
scrollView2.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {
                // Assuming horizontal scrollview

                if(scrollView2.getScrollX() != prevScrollX_for2)
                {
                    // Do something
                }
                prevScrollX_for2 = getScrollX();
            }
        });
```